# android - Navigation graph Flow Preview in landscape

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

The navigation graph preview of Android jetpack components always shows a portrait view of screens for the screens in the layout editor. Can we customize this to view the screens on an emulator of our choice?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Android Studio 4.1.1 it is possible to switch between screen orientations in the navigation graph preview screen by tapping `o` key (the letter 'O', not the number 0).

Comment: I hit 'o' by accident--thanks for helping me get back to normal.

Comment: Is this still supported? It always stays in portrait mode for me, even if I put all of my res files to layout-land folder.